# firends of cake bootstrap-ui change color

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bootstrap-ui

I installed the https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui plugin with the install command. I'd like to change the primary color, where is the right place to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's kinda unrelated to the plugin, except for that the `install` command will install the compiled distribution assets, and at that point you cannot change things like theme colors anymore.

Modifying bootstrap theme colors (or any other variables for that matter) is only possible when compiling it on your own, see the bootstrap docs for more information:

**https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/theming/**